# Changing 0.00 price to retail price from attribute see details

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

We have about 250 items in Magento 1.9 community that got migrated over with 0.00 showing as price.  This was because old site had it set that way.  However the retail price is there and it is set as one of the attributes prices.  Is there anyway to fix this without doing each one manually?

Thanks

Comment: Migrated from What?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load a collection of your product catalog, loop through each, and save the "retail price" to Magento's "price" field. Do this in Magento Shell script or as a standalone script.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $retailPrice = $product->getRetailPrice();
    $product->setPrice($retailPrice);
    $product->save();
}
```